# Copying layer comp positioning in Photoshop CS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'm designing a iOS interface that had some last minute changes to the tab bar (across the bottom) and many of the screens had already been set up as Photoshop Layer Comps maintaining visibility, positioning and appearance.

Now that I've made my tweaks to the tab bar I need the new tab bar positioning in all of my existing layer comps.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this without having to go through each comp and adjust?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, because I use Groups instead of Layer Comps. I've found Layer Comps to be really, really frustrating to use for app states when designing for iOS, so I don't use them.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest solution at this point is probably to pick one comp, record an Action that nudges the tab bar to the new location, then use that Action on each of the rest of the comps. Assign a kbsc and it gets quite fast.

[Update: June 2014]
All of the problems mentioned in this question are solved in Photoshop CC 2014, which allows Layer Comps within Smart Objects (think "button states") to be selected individually without opening the SO. These selections are included in Layer Styles in the master document.

Synching positions, attributes or visibilities simultaneously across multiple selected Layer Comps is now a feature of the Layer Comps panel.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got one visual element -- on its own layer -- that's being used across multiple LayerComps, and that element needs a change to be applied universally on all those LayerComps:

1. Select all your LayerComp states at once
2. Make the necessary change
3. Hit the update-layer-comps button while all the LayerComp states are still highlighted.

The change should be applied to all states simultaneously.

Comment: But this makes all layer comps exactly the same?! I.e. it overwrites all your layer comps with the current document state, causing complete loss of all layer comp data.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner, I see what you're saying, and here's how I avoided that from happening. I have a layer group which appears in 15 layer comps in the same position, and I need to move it to a new position in all layer comps. (1) Move the layer group to the new position in one of the layer comps. (2) Make sure the layer group is selected. Make sure the updated layer comp is selected. (3) Now select all of the layer comps too. (4) Use the "Update Position" button in the Layer Comps panel (not the Refresh symbol button). Now the layer group should be repositioned in all layer comps.

Answer (score 0):

Are your layercomps using the "position" feature? I find it annoying.

I would go through to each layer comp and open its "LayerComp Options" dialog. And there turn OFF  Position and Appearance.  Just use the layercomps to track Visibility.

Then when you move something, it moves on all layercomps.

Comment: I was using positioning, but after turning it off at the point I was at each comp was completely out of whack.  Noted for the future though.  I use positioning on lengthier screens so that I can create several comps as if the user had swiped up/down.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that works in some situations is to duplicate the layer or group to a new file, and bring it back in and update your comps with the 'new' group/layer and delete the old one. Only works if what you are sending out and bringing back in has the same position/appearance/visibility across most of your comps, otherwise, you're still going to have to go in and move/change appearance on things comp by comp.

Layer comps are one of those things that sound awesome, become vital to your workflow, and ultimately leave you with a feeling of wanting to dope slap Adobe for not fully polishing the feature.